# Public Array? Making array accessible by multiple classes

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode

I am trying to save lessons in a day (from text-fields) into an array so that I can save them, and later display them on a new view.

My current code:

```
//monLessons = Monday's lessons

NSMutableArray *monLessons;

monLessons = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: self.mon1.text, self.mon2.text, self.mon3.text, self.mon4.text, self.mon5.text, self.mon6.text, nil];
```

Cheers!

Comment: You could use a Singleton, or save them (NSUserDefault, CoreData, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just this one `NSMutableArray` that you want to access from multiple classes - `NSUserDefaults` would be the easiest and cleanest solution.

**Example**

So save the NSMutableArray:

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:YOUR ARRAY forKey:@"MondayLessons"];
```

Now `NSUserDefaults` returns a immutable copy of the a array when you ask for it - you will need to return it like this:

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"MondayLessons"] mutableCopy];
```

This way you get an `NSMutableArray` back and not an `NSArray`

**Edit 2**

I forgot to add:

Before you close your application or move to a new ViewController - you need to save the data to `NSUserDefaults` So please call - `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];`

Anytime you want to save. If you don't call this line of code - when you ask `NSUserDefaults` for your Array - it will be nil. You need to do this every time you make a change to the array you're saving.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate it. So now I can just use the same method of getting the array elements right?

Comment: Once you have the array back you can access it as you wish, correct. Glad it helped.

Comment: @user3451074 Please see my answer - updated it with info I forgot. Sorry about that.